# My openID Authentication return 'You must have either https wrappers or curl enabled.'

Tags: php, authentication, openid, steam

I've a OpenID connection in place who was working yesterday and today i'm unable to connect when i'm on my local server i've also the same openID online and it works perfectly fine. it throw me the error 'You must have either https wrappers or curl enabled.' when I click on the login button

I've saw on another post this:

'Have you tried adding or uncommenting extension=php_curl.dll or extension=php_openssl.dll to your php.ini?'

I've tried it but didn't worked for me.

BTW my phpmyadmin return also :
'The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration. See our documentation for more information.'

Comment: When you enabled the extension(s), did you restart the PHP process?

Comment: Yes, I've stoped the server and restart it if it is what you mean

Comment: Post your phpinfo(). It seems you miss php extensions. What do you mean when you say _I've tried it but didn't worked for me_? You get errors?

Comment: I've got no error by doing it it just as done nothing, maybe i've edit the wrong php.ini I don't realy know. there a lot of info in the phpinfo() can't post everything here

Comment: In the phpinfo output, it will tell you exactly which files it has processed. It will also list the extensions which have been successfully enabled. If it doesn't list the file you edited, or the extension you tried to load, that's a massive clue.